# C# user control event equivalent in Qt

Tags: c#, qt, user-controls, event-handling, widget

In C# I used to create an user control and define custom event to pass data to my main class like this:

```
public delegate void MyCustomEventDelegate(int x);
public MyCustomEventDelegate MyCustomEvent;
```

I'm new to Qt. I learned that widgets in Qt are equivalent to user controls in C#. So I created a widget and added it to my main window. Since it listens for a UDP port, I want to pass incoming data to main window. How can I do this via events? How can I create custom event for a widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qt you have an architecture similar, but not quite the same, to C# events/delegates.

In [Qt, you have signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). The simplest way you can think of is that a signal is an event, while a slot is an event handler.

Qt defines the `slots` and `signals` macros to help you define these. For example, the simplest definition for a signal and slot would be:

```
public slots:
     void setValue(int value);

signals:
     void valueChanged(int newValue);

....

void Counter::setValue(int value)
{
    if (value != m_value) {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChanged(value);
    }
}
```

And you wire them up like this:

```
Counter a, b;
QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

a.setValue(12);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12
b.setValue(48);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 48
```

Here calling `a.setValue` is the equivalent of raising an event in C#. You can read more specifics at the link I posted.

In your case you need to define one or more signals in the widget and one or more slots in the main window. You can `connect` them when the widget is added to the window.

Comment: Where's emit valueChanged()?

Comment: In my main window, I did this:

 ui->setupUi(this);
 connect(ui->widget_first, SIGNAL(TestSignal()), this, SLOT(TestSlot()));
 
In the widget I did this:

 signals:
  void TestSignal();
  
But when I call TestSignal in my widget, TestSlot function doesn't fire.

Comment: @MustafaChelik: Is `widget_first` initialized when you call connect? Also, is the slot properly defined in the main window class?

Comment: @fxam: Yes, missed that bit, but it was available in the link. Added it now.

Comment: @MarcelN. Would like to point out that it's inappropriate to say calling setValue() is equivalent to raising event. It's **emit valueChanged()** that does.